# Possible to overload curly braces?

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading

I'm almost sure that not, but I didn't find a difinitive answer to that:

Is it possible to overload the curly braces? As in:

```
class Foo
{
    int i;
    public:
    int operator{}(int _i){return _i+42;};    
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f{2};
    return 0;
}
```

It is never mentioned, neither as allowed nor as not allowed. gcc 4.6 doesn't compile it, but that doesn't mean it is not allowed by the standard, right?

Comment: Sorry steffen, c++ does not let you overload curly braces :(

Comment: What would the arguments be?  An operator has operands, which are passed to the overload.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C++ curly braces `{}` are not operators unlike the `[]` (Array subscripting operator) or `()` (Function call operator), so they can't be overloaded.

Comment: Additionally, overloadable operators are enumerated in `[over.oper]`. Since `{}` does not appear in the list, it cannot be overloaded.

Comment: @bdonlan `=` and `,` _do_ appear in the list, but can only be overloaded when they are operators; the overloads are ignored when they are punctuation.  (Thus, `f(a, b)` ignores any overloaded `operator,()`, but `f((a, b))` doesn't.)