# How do you use roster notation in a template class?

Tags: c++

Lets say I have a linked list class that I wrote, how would I be able to initialize it using roster notation?
Similar to how arrays are declared i.e. int test[3] = {1,2,3}

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10528347/7361656

The curly bracees is not an operator,therefore it is not overridable, meaning it can only do what it was meant to do.

you can write a constructor that gets a vector/an array that initializes it and implement a copy-constructor. 
That way, when you will call: `class object=vector` it will first convert the vector to an object of your class and than assign it to your instance.